# gulp watch not work when use absolute path?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am setting a gulp development environment, but when I used an absolute path in gulp watcher, it didn't work.Does gulp watcher support absolute path?

### gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(
        path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/**/*.css'), 
        gulp.parallel('dev:css', 'dev:cssImgs')
    );
});
```

Comment: The question for me is, why do you want to use absolute path there? Gulp is meant to use relative paths, so why change this? But I would think, it should work with absolute too ...

Comment: @eisbehr I have tried relative path, it works. But absolute path didn't work.

Comment: I spent 90 minutes before I figured out absolute path was the cause of my watch not working!

Answer (score 2):

I found the same error, and sorry for necroing this question in 2019., but this problem isn't solved yet.

It seems that watch process only accept relative paths written in unix style. It won't accept absolute paths or even relative paths with back slashes (windows style).

Using node `path` to clear out the path won't help on windows, so only solution would be to use node `path.normalize('..\\your\\relative\\path\\')` and then replace `\\` with `/`.

I wrote one simple function that I will normalize path in unix way no matter on which OS it's used.

```js
/*
 This plugin is used to fix path separators for dynamically created links used
 for `gulp watch` command.

 It converts links like
 `../../some//path\with/wrong//\separators/`
 to
 `../../some/path/with/wrong/separators/`

 It also replaces `~` with user home directory path
*/

module.exports = (oldPath) => {
 const pathString = oldPath;
 const fix = /\\{1,}|\/{1,}/;
 const user_home = require('os').homedir();

 return pathString.replace(new RegExp(fix, 'gm'), '/').replace(new RegExp(fix, 'gm'), '/').replace('~', user_home)
}
```

Save that code as `fixPath.js` and then use it in this manner:

```js
const fixPath = require('./fixPath')

let badPath = '../../some//path\with/wrong//\separators/'

let goodPath = fixPath(badPath) // "../../some/path/with/wrong/separators/"
```